# Zend Framework is throwing an error when trying to enable modules

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I am new to zend Framework. I am trying to enable the module functionality, but when i try to do it using the command line  i get the following error message:

An Error Has Occurred
 Dispatcher error - actionable method not found

The command i am using is the following: /zf.sh enable module

If anybody can help i would be very thankful.

thank you.
Miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add the following lines in application.ini

(resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = "" )